# Is it possible to add an image as a class attribute?

Tags: android, image, imageview, png

I'm creating a class that will hold different dishes, and its properties are the title, the difficulty, the type and the time. But I also want an Image that will be displayed when an object of that class is created. How can I set an image, .png as an attribute of a class?

Here's the code:

```
public class Dish {

    private String name;
    private String time;
    private String type;
    private Whatevergoesinhere image;
    private int difficulty;


    public Dish(String name, String time, String type, Whatevergoesinhere image, int difficulty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.type = type;
        this.image = image;
        this.difficulty= difficulty;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Whatevergoesinhere getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public static final Dish[] dishes = {
            new Dish("Judías verdes con patatas", "45 min.", "verduras", "R.id.ic_launcher_background.xml", )
    }
}
```

I've tried using BufferedImage, but it's not supported in Android.

Please help, if you have any idea just tell.

Comment: Another option is [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap). Or it could be just a reference to an image that's stored somewhere else than in the object itself.

Comment: If you get these images from application resources (`res` folder) then you can just pass drawable ID that will be later used to set image resource on an `ImageView`.

Comment: @Jenea Vranceanu do I pass the id as an int or aí what? Because I have to set the typo of attribute of the class in order to use it in the declaration of a new Dish object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my commentary: *"If you get these images from application resources (`res` folder) then you can just pass drawable ID that will be later used to set image resource on an `ImageView`."*

In order to do that you need to change `image` variable declaration to this:

```
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes
// import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes: Use this import if you are using AndroidX dependencies

public class Dish {

    ...
    @DrawableRes
    private int image;
    ...
```

And then you also need to change constructor and getter method declarations to this form:

```
    public Dish(..., @DrawableRes int image, ...) {
        ...
        this.image = image;
        ...
    }

    ...

    @DrawableRes
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }
```

Later when this data holding class is used you can simply use [ImageView.setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) to display an image you have.